# show foreign column in frontend with typo3 fluid

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-flow

My table Person has name column and a foreign key column from Position table, so how can I display the label of my table Position corresponding to the current Person and save it.

```
table Person                          Position
uid name position(foreign key)        uid label_position
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this a 1:1 relation ? You can use {person.position.label_position}

Comment: How is this handled in n:m relations?